# why graph plots are hiding in coreplots ios? How do i bring front from the axis set?

Tags: objective-c, ios, graph, core-plot

Now i am working on core plots integration... In my graph plots are hided by the axis set i need to bring my plots front of the axis set is there any idea ....

how do i achieve that....

**my code:**

```
CGRect frame = [self.hostingView bounds];
myGraphForPopulation = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.hostingView.clipsToBounds=YES;
  ......
  ......
 axisSet.xAxis.zPosition=0;
 axisSet.yAxis.zPosition=0;
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `zPosition` of the axes; you can delete those lines. If you look closely, you'll see that the plots are already in front of the axes, they're just getting clipped at the edge of the plot area.

The solution here is to do the following:

1. Adjust the padding to move the edges of the plot area out. Decrease the padding on the graph and increase the corresponding padding on the plot area frame.
2. Increase the plot ranges of the plot space to account for the extra size of the plot area.
3. Set the `visibleRange` and/or `gridLinesRange` on each axis so the lines stop at the correct point.

See the "Control Chart" and "Vertical Bar Chart" plots in the Plot Gallery example app for sample code.